# Вопрос по корректировке скрипта Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пишу скрипт, который бы выводил список пользователей, у которых есть дубликаты учетных записей (с одного ip и устройства авторизация). Мне нужно, чтобы в выборку попадал только список тех пользователей, у которых дубликаты свежие (т.е. созданы недавно, за последний месяц).
Никак не могу понять, как встроить.

```
select 
distinct user_id, 
  status, created_at 

from ...
  
where 
  users.created_at >= (current_date - 2)
  
and (ip, device) 
IN

(
select 
ip, device

from 
...

inner join ... on ...

inner join ... on ...

group by ip, device

having COUNT(distinct user_id) >=3

and /вот здесь не могу никак сообразить, как добавить условие про дату создания таких дубликатов/)
```

Пробовал добавить and created_at >= (current_date - 30) - не помогает, список не выгружается совсем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Основная ошибка в ряде случаев - излишняя сложность.*
На мой взгляд, **вам надо иметь во WHERE комбинированную проверку на период и на уникальность пользователя (её - вложенным запросом).** И всё.

1. У вас же *идея верная, но много лишнего* (или это не описано в условии).
2. Кроме того, вы *условие проверки единичных записей* (должно быть во WHERE) *пытаетесь поместить в проверку агрегированных записей* (HAVING), что принципиально *не должно работать*.
3. И не могу судить о работе в postgresql *синтаксис*а `created_at >= (current_date - 30)` - *в mySQL это работать не будет точно*.

Синтаксис postgresql я не знаю, так что **проверил работу кода ниже на mySQL.
Основной принцип - рабочий, можете подправить, что надо, и проверить у себя.**
Сам код - последние 7 строк, все остальное - создание тестового примера.

```
CREATE TABLE calls(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id VARCHAR (25),
    status_1 VARCHAR (25),
    ip VARCHAR (25), 
    device VARCHAR (25),
    created_at DATETIME    
);
INSERT INTO calls (user_id, status_1, ip, device,created_at)
    VALUES
    ("Петя", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.1', 'модем', '2018-05-25 21:25:54'),
    ("Маша", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.2', 'синхрофазатрон', '2018-05-25 22:22:22'),
    ("Вася", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.3', 'табурет', '2018-05-25 21:25:54'),
    ("Петя", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.1', 'модем', '2018-05-26 22:25:54'),
    ("Маша", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.2', 'синхрофазатрон', '2022-08-03 01:01:01'),
    ("Гена", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.4', 'ванна', '2022-08-04 01:01:01')
;
SELECT * FROM calls;
SELECT user_id, status_1, ip, device,created_at
FROM calls
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= DATE(created_at) and (ip, device) IN (
    SELECT ip, device 
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY ip, device
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

**Результат** (отброшены все 4 записи старых, а также отброшен Гена, который появился первый раз. Зато Маша уличена во вторичной регистрации и включена в вывод):

```
Affected rows: 0

Affected rows: 6

Query result:
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | status_1    | ip          | device         | created_at          |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1  | Петя    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.1 | модем          | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 |
| 2  | Маша    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.2 | синхрофазатрон | 2018-05-25 22:22:22 |
| 3  | Вася    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.3 | табурет        | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 |
| 4  | Петя    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.1 | модем          | 2018-05-26 22:25:54 |
| 5  | Маша    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.2 | синхрофазатрон | 2022-08-03 01:01:01 |
| 6  | Гена    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.4 | ванна          | 2022-08-04 01:01:01 |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
Affected rows: 6

Query result:
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| user_id | status_1    | ip          | device         | created_at          |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| Маша    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.2 | синхрофазатрон | 2022-08-03 01:01:01 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
Affected rows: 1
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо Вам большое за ответ! Половина проблемы решилась)) Есть нюанс, о котором я не упомянул - у пользователей в большинстве случаев идет несколько авторизаций (есть отдельная таблица с логами по авторизации конкретных пользователей). Ваш скрипт я подредактировал под Postgre, но теперь упирается все в то, что в выборке считаются не уникальные пользователи по ip и устройству, созданные за определенный промежуток, а их авторизации (это все про подзапрос). Например ищу пользователей с более 3х дубликатов аккаунтов свежими, а выходят пользователи с 2 свежими и парой старых

Comment: 1) Создайте новый вопрос на этом сайте, описав задачу хорошо (как минимум, структура таблиц, но желательно и пример данных на входе, что должно быть на выходе и что получается). Описание в комментарии выше мне не понятно. 2) По данному вопросу "Вопрос по корректировке скрипта Postgresql": рекомендую действовать по моему первому комментарию (см.выше) под ответом:-)

Comment: Понял, спасибо))